# Replace comma with point and remove all points but last regex

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to do the following: change comma separator to point and remove all points but last (e.g. 123,123.11 -> 123.123.11 -> 123123.11)

this is how I do it:

```js
let val = '123,123.11'

val = val ? val.replace(',', '.').replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '') : '';

console.log(val)
```

is it possible to do it with just one replace instead of two?
(I'm pretty sure it is, but I'm noob at regex, so would appreciate all answers as well as how you learned regex)

stupid me just realized why I was changing all commas to points first because if I switch to german language the number becomes `42.334,83`my formatting becomes incorrect with `.replace(/,/g, '') : ''`, so I firstly change all commas to points and then removed all points except last, but that seems such a clumsy solution

Comment: why you dont want like this `"123,123.11".replace(',', '')` ?

Comment: @VadimHulevich wouldn't `.replace(/,/g, '')` be better?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn simple replace much faster (better performance) then regexp

Comment: But what if there is more than one comma?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its all number with ',' and '.' you can use the following `/[^0-9](?=.*\.)/g`

```js
let val = '123,123,123.11'

val = val ? val.replace(/[^0-9](?=.*\.)/g, '') : '';

console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, via `/,|\.(?=.*\.)/`

The idea is to use the RegEx `|` (pipe) character to match and replace all commas in addition to the periods you're matching.

```js
let val = '123,123.11'

val = val ? val.replace(/,|\.(?=.*\.)/g, '') : '';

console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const result =  "55,123,123.11".replace(/,/g, '');
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a non-regex solution, you could split on the commas and join with an empty string.

```js
console.log('123,123.11'.split(',').join(''))

console.log('123,456,789.987'.split(',').join(''))
```